# Reference request for the irreps of the Spin group

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, spin-geometry

I'm searching for a reference request where all irreducible representations of the Spin group or of $\mathfrak{so}(n)$ are classified. It seems to be 'well-known' that the Lie algebras correspond to dynkin diagrams in the $B$ and $D$ series, but the exact correspondence is not mentioned. It also appears to be well-known that all representations except the spinorial representation can be found by repeatedly tensoring the lowest-dimensional representation with itself.

However, the only source I can find for all these statements is comments on SE and non-referenced claims on Wikipedia. I guess that shows that this subject is seen as complete or easy. There is a lot of literature about $Spin(3)$, mostly from physics, but I'm struggling to find any real sources about $Spin(n)$ in general. I would appreciate it very much for someone could give me a reference.

Comment: I'm away from my books for a few days, but my recollection is that all of this is in Fulton and Harris's book "Representation theory"

Comment: @JasonDeVito Thank you! Reading the TOC it seems chapters 18-20 are precisely about special orthogonal and Spin groups.